# My placement is broken on Bootstrap 4 any ideas?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm designing a web page with Bootstrap 4 and I can't get my head around why this placement is wrong. I've literally been staring at my code for like a good 15 minutes now and I have no clue why.

My code is:

```html
<div class="container">

  <br/>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img src="img-side01a.jpg" width="555">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: #5892EF;">

      <h2 style="color: white; @font-face{ font-family: bloomer; src: url('headerfont.otf');}">About Us</h2>

      <p style="color: white; font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';">text here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: #5892EF;">
      <h2 style="color: white; @font-face{ font-family: bloomer; src: url('headerfont.otf');}">Mission Statement <img src="img-icon01a.png" width="25" height="25"></h2>
      <p style="color: white; font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';">text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img src="img-side01b.png" class="img-fluid" width="555">
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <hr> copyright
</div>
```

But there's just this gap that I can't get rid of. I've tried using the first image for the second one and that makes no difference...

[image](https://omegasmarts.cf/jjfghjg.PNG)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gap is because you defined 2 rows.You can put all col-md classes in one row.Your current codes second row columns will automatically come below first row elements without any space.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row no-gutters">
<div class="col-md-6" style="padding:0px;">
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" width="100%" height="50px">
    </div>
<div class="col-md-6 " style="background-color: #5892EF;">

<h2 style="color: white; ">About Us</h2>
<p style="color: white; font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';">text here</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 " style="background-color: #5892EF;">
<h6 style="color: white;">Mission Statement</h6> 
<p style="color: white; font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';">text here</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6" style="padding:0px;">
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" width="100%" height="50px">
</div>
</div>
```

Try this code.It was not your fault.Bootstraps col-md class bydefault keeping 15px padding.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't very clear on this one, I meant the gap on the sides and in the middle if you look closely.

Comment: Did you used any external css?If yes then please share that css file code

Comment: Nope (15 chars)